# WPF: inserting data into ListBox placed in ListBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, listbox, listboxitem

I'm trying to create fancy looking `Listbox`. `ListBoxItem`s are supposed to expand after being selected, but the problem is, they're also supposed to contain another `ListBox` filled with some details about particular item and I have no idea how to put some data into it. 
I've tried both accessing it from C# code and binding it in XAML but I'm still nowhere near the solution.

```
<UserControl.Resources>        
    <ResourceDictionary>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SelectedTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path = Order}" Style="{StaticResource SampleListCellItem}" MinWidth="35"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path = FullName}" Style="{StaticResource SampleListCellItem}" Width="340"/>                     
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path = FirstName}" Style="{StaticResource SampleListCellItem}" Width="200" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path = BirthDate, StringFormat = d}" Style="{StaticResource SampleListCellItem}" Width="100"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <ListBox Name="InnerList" Height="200" Width="200"/>
                    <Button Name="Button1" Height="40" Width="100" Content="ButtonText" Visibility="Visible"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path = Order}" Style="{StaticResource SampleListCellItem}" MinWidth="35"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path = FullName}" Style="{StaticResource SampleListCellItem}" Width="340"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path = FirstName}" Style="{StaticResource SampleListCellItem}" Width="200" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path = BirthDate, StringFormat = d}" Style="{StaticResource SampleListCellItem}" Width="100"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="ContainerStyle">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource SelectedTemplate}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your item that you want to display, I assume you have a property that is a list (of T) or other type that is compatible with a normal listbox itemsource. Let name it ListPr for the sake of example.

In your data template, add a listBox control and set the ItemsSource to {Binding Path = ListPr }. It should works just like that. In that new listbox, you will be able to define another data template, and so on.

Like it's mentioned in another post though, a treeview might be what you need in this case.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're looking for is a tree. I think the [TreeView](http://www.google.ca/search?q=wpf+treeview) control would be ideal for what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank You both for an answer and sorry for the delay in responding. David's solution works like a charm. Thanks